# Android widget installation

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a problem with the widget. This is a simple widget counting down to a fixed date. The problem is that some devices do not want to install the widget. On the emulator in eclipse is the same one to another does not work. Does not have any errors.

What is the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the information on the cause for this by deploying your application through an IDE such as IntelliJ Idea, or Eclipse.

In IntelliJ Idea, after building all files, during deployment the `Run` dialog shows you the status of the install. In case of a failure it would display the reason too.

Generally during debugging it's reasons like installations from different machines (which would show something like `[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES]`). It might be  due to the keystore from where the certs are installed has changed.